# iOS Restore IAP on other devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a non-renewing subscription in my app, and I'm looking for a way to restore it on other devices. I stored the datas on the user iCloud account, but when there is no account logged in, we can't store it and there is no way to get it on another devices. I don't have login system on my app, so I can't get user reference on database.

Please, is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

That's what the "Restore purchase" APIs are for. Also, if a user buys the IAP again, they won't be charged, though Apple may object during App Review.